# Beating iterative alpha beta search in Isolation Game

Tags: alpha-beta-pruning, iddfs

I'm having trouble beating an AI in Isolation game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(board_game) with 3 queens on a 7x7 board. I tried applying alpha beta iteration with a scoring function on the state. I tried 3 scoring functions:

1. (0.75/# moves taken) * number of legal moves - (# moves taken/0.75) * number of opponent legal moves
2. number of legal moves - 3 * number of opponent legal moves
3. 3 * number of legal moves - number of opponent legal moves

The first is an annealed aggressive strategy so the agent gets more aggressive as the game goes longer. The 2nd is a pure aggression strat and the last is a pure defensive strat. None of them consistently beat standard alpha beta iteration with the state scoring function: number of legal moves -  number of opponent legal moves. They all broke roughly even.

Any suggestions of scoring state functions or search algorithms are appreciated. The search has a limit of 6000 seconds per turn though.

Comment: What is your main **specific** question here? Please, choose one specific question and put it in the body **and** title of your post to clarify what you're asking here.

Comment: I'm simply asking for a search algorithm with a cost function that can do better than iterative alpha beta

Comment: Is your question somehow related to this: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/5174/2444?